# how to use join in web api and display two table data

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api2

I want to display two tables data using join in web api. I have tried with this code, but getting error - **The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.** and here is my code

```
public List<tblEmpTask> GettblEmpTasks()
        {
var q = (from n in db.tblEmpTasks
                     join c in db.tblEmployees on n.intEmpCode equals c.intEmpCode

                     select new
                     {
                         n.strTaskName,
                         n.dtStart,
                         c.strEmployeeName,

                     }).ToList();
            return q;
}
```

Any solution will be helpful.

Comment: the error that you get means that the variables that you base your join on are not of the same type. Have checked if maybe one of 2 is nullable?

Comment: which variables?